# calculating avg values from ordered dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an ordered list whose items are a pair of values in the format below. I want to calculate the avg millisecond (right values) time per each unique second (left values)

Is there a simple way to do that?

```
20170822-13:56:02 :  50 ms

20170822-13:56:03 :  36 ms

20170822-13:56:03 :  59 ms

20170822-13:56:03 :  40 ms

20170822-13:56:03 :  67 ms
```

Comment: The data you provide is not a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the result for your example should be **{'20170822-13:56:02': 50.0, '20170822-13:56:03': 50.5}** here is a solution:

```
raw_input = [
    '20170822-13:56:02 :  50 ms',
    '20170822-13:56:03 :  36 ms',
    '20170822-13:56:03 :  59 ms',
    '20170822-13:56:03 :  40 ms',
    '20170822-13:56:03 :  67 ms'
]

result_dict = {}

for raw_input_item in raw_input:
    # Transform inpu item in a two item list alo [second, millisecond]. e.g. ['20170822-13:56:03', '67'].
    key_value = raw_input_item.rstrip('ms').split(' :  ')
    # Accumulate the total milliseconds and the count entries for each second, so we can calculate average at the end.
    value = result_dict.get(key_value[0], False)
    if value:
        # The key exist, just add one to the entries counter and the milliseconds to the total milliseconds to that key (second)
        value[0] += 1
        value[1] += int(key_value[1])
    else:
        # The key do not exist, just initialize the value with entry counter 1 and the total milliseconds
        # the this first key appearance bring with it.
        result_dict[key_value[0]] = [1, int(key_value[1])]

for key in result_dict:
    result_dict[key] = result_dict[key][1]/result_dict[key][0]

print(result_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your dict doesn't seem to be correct as you have multiple entries with the same key. But anyway, assuming you have a properly formatted OrderedDict (like the one I generate below) you can get the average like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
x = OrderedDict()
x['a'] = 1 
x['b'] = 2 
x['c'] = 3 
avg = np.average(list(x.values()))
```

which returns `2.0` as the answer for `avg`

Comment: Or as a one-liner: `sum([i for i in x.values()])/len(list(x.values()))`

Comment: ```avg = np.average(list(x.values()))``` is a one-liner if he had the OrderedDict already...

Comment: That is true, and probably more readable. If anything my solution only relies on std libraries which may or may not be needed.

Comment: Using std libraries was not in the question :)